# Obter lista de dados removendo duplicações por atributo

Tags: kotlin

Possuo os seguintes data classes

```
data class Item {
    order: Order
}

data class Order {
    orderItems: List<OrderItem>
}

data class OrderItem {
    payments: List<Payment>
}

data class Payment {
    id: Long
}
```

E que por sua vez tenho um `list<Item>`. E o que eu estou precisando é obter todos os Payments que não são duplicados, ou seja, todos com o `payment.id diferentes.

Estou tentando juntar todos os payments de todos os items e order items, e depois realizar algum distinct, porém não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Alguém sabe alguma estratégia para isso ?

Edit:

Criei uma implementação bem força bruta:

```
val list = mutableListOf<Payment>()

items.forEach { item ->
    item.order?.orderItems?.forEach { orderItem ->
        orderItem.payments.forEach { payment ->
            if (list.none { it.id == payment.id }) {
                list.add(payment)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Não vou entrar no mérito de o porque você tem pagamentos duplicados. Existem algumas abordagens possíveis, porém, optei pela que menos altera seu código.

As suas classes continuam as mesmas:

```
data class Item(val order: Order)

data class Order(val orderItem: OrderItem)

data class OrderItem(val payments: List<Payment>)

data class Payment(val id: Long)
```

Na classe `OrderItem`, adicionei uma função que realiza a [desduplicação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desduplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados) dos pagamentos com base no seu `id`.

```
data class OrderItem(val payments: List<Payment>) {

   fun deduplicatePayments(): List<Payment> {
       return payments.distinctBy { it.id }
   }
}
```

Então para utilizar basta apenas fazer a chamada:

```
item.order.orderItem.deduplicatePayments()
```

Ps: Ficaria melhor, se você tivesse um objeto que representasse sua lista de pagamentos, e lá dentro tivesse essa função que realiza a desduplicação.

Dessa forma, você poderia fazer um `item.order.orderItem.payments.deduplicate()`

Porém, como eu disse, optei por não alterar seu código, já que isso seria apenas uma escolha de design.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que talvez uma outra solução seria utilizar uma `extension function` para tratar da desduplicação. O meu exemple é este:

```
fun List<Payment>.distinct() = this.distinctBy { it.id }

fun main() {
    val payments = listOf(Payment(1), Payment(2), Payment(4), Payment(1))
    println(payments.distinct())
}
```

`Item`, `Order`, `OrderItem` parecem não fazer parte de `Payment` e portanto não os tomei em consideraçãp para este código. Fazer funções dentro de `data classes` não é aconselhavél porque `data classes` são feitas especificamente para portar dados e apenas em casos excepcionais pode ser útil criar funções dentro de `data classes` o que não me parece ser o caso aquí. Outra coisa importante é que estas `data classes` conforme na descrição, não compilam por várias razões mas mais propriamente porque não se encontram na posição de argumentos do construtor e uma vez que não têm nem `var` e nem `val` atribuido o compilador não sabe o que fazer com elas. Espero que isto ajude!